# It's better to use knockoutjs or angularjs with visualsource page(apex)

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app

I am new on Salesforce1, developing an app using knockoutjs but app is not working on iPad like scrolling,data loading and binding ect. I am facing more problem like this please suggest something. We should use apex code or html 5 is good for mobile app..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every framework has its pros and cons. It totally depends on your requirement. Sometimes even jquery mobile can solve your issue. Check out this unit on Trailhead to learn about all mobile frameworks and select which is best for you.

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1_mobile_frameworks

Comment: Thanks Prakash, but I am facing more problem using these tech